# set colour to multiple non sequential parts of a spannable text android

Tags: java, android, textview, spannablestring

I have a spannable text. It has a string for eg, TO, BE, IS, DO. I'm reading an arraylist from database [BE, DO]. I'm trying to change the colour of BE and DO. 
My java code:

```
Spannable spans;
private void clickableDictionary(String words) {

    final ForegroundColorSpan fcs = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(33, 150, 243));

    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(words.split(", ")));
    String vocab = object.fetchDataVOCAB(getApplicationContext(), wordLength);
    ArrayList<String> myListVOCAB = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(vocab.split(", ")));

    words_done.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()); //words_done is the textView
    words_done.setText(words, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
    spans = (Spannable) words_done.getText();
    if (myListVOCAB.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "") != "") {
        System.out.println("-------VOCAB: "+myListVOCAB+" size of done words: "+myList.size());
        int indexStart;
        int indexEnd;

        for (int i = 0; i < myListVOCAB.size(); i++) {

            indexStart = words.indexOf(myListVOCAB.get(i));
            System.out.println("-------VOCAB startIndex: "+indexStart+"for loop index:---"+i);
            indexEnd = indexStart + (myListVOCAB.get(i).length());
            System.out.println("-------VOCAB endIndex: " + indexEnd);

            spans.setSpan(fcs, indexStart, indexEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            System.out.println("-------color change startIndex: " + indexStart + "endIndex:---" + indexEnd);
        }
    }

        BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getWordInstance(Locale.US);
        iterator.setText(words);
        int start = iterator.first();
        for (int end = iterator.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = iterator
                .next()) {
            String possibleWord = words.substring(start, end);
            if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(possibleWord.charAt(0))) {
                ClickableSpan clickSpan = getClickableSpan(possibleWord, start, end);

                spans.setSpan(clickSpan, start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            }
        }

}

private ClickableSpan getClickableSpan(final String word, final int start, final int end) {
    return new ClickableSpan() {
        final String mWord;
        {
            mWord = word;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {

            String s = object.fetchDataVOCAB(getApplicationContext(), wordLength);

            if (s.isEmpty()) {
                s = mWord;
                object.writeVOCAB(getApplicationContext(), wordLength, s, vocabCount + 1);
                vocab.setText("Vocab: " + object.readVOCAB(getApplicationContext(), wordLength));
            }

            else {
                if (!s.contains(mWord)) {
                    s = s + ", " + mWord;
                    object.writeVOCAB(getApplicationContext(), wordLength, s, object.readVOCAB(getApplicationContext(), wordLength) + 1);
                    vocab.setText("Vocab: " + object.readVOCAB(getApplicationContext(), wordLength));
                }
            }

            spans.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(33, 150, 243)), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            new atask().execute(mWord);
            widget.invalidate();
        }

        public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {// override updateDrawState
            ds.setUnderlineText(false); // set to false to remove underline
        }

    };

}
```

myList contains the words i want to print as clickable. myListVOCAB contains the word I want to print in blue. I'm populating these from databases. Also I'm trying to make a word blue at the very moment when it is clicked as well.
My problem is when the intent is started only one word is printed in blue, the last word of myListVOCAB. I think I'm not using the setSpan method accordingly. Please share some suggestions on how to set parts of spannable to change colour where the parts are not pre-set in string.

Answer (score 0):

The way to Change the Color for String you got from List as follows :

```
TextView TV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(list.get(0));  



wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 15, 30, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Now you need to manage the text from list only.

Comment: Will you please explain a little more? I don't understand your answer properly I think. I need to print the blue words and the non-blue words in the same spannable text. The blue words also must be clickable. @Rajan Bhavsar

Comment: In the third statement we have to set the index for Text first position and last position for which we need to set the color as blue.

Comment: yes I get that. My point is How can i print like, 
"BE(blue), IS(black), DO(blue), NO(black), ON(black)" in the same spannable so that all are clickable? @Rajan Bhavsar

Comment: Are you have predefined string such as if the string is BE then we compare the string and print that string with blue and so on.

Comment: When I'm doing that only the last string is getting blue. Please check the strings below,
I want:  "BE(blue), IS(black), DO(blue), NO(black), ON(black)"
I'm getting:  "BE(black-WRONG as I want it blue), IS(black), DO(blue), NO(black), ON(black)"

Comment: i feel that the Issue is coming from your coding side as if that is not possible then why that spannable set the color blue for  DO. So, please check out your code.

Comment: only one start_index and end_index can be mentioned in setSpan method that is why this is happening. Can you help me with any alternative method? Thanks for your responses.